# Fieldset and margin collapse

Tags: html, css

Why does it seem impossible to collapse margins on `fieldset` and `legend` ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
}

fieldset,
legend,
div,
h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

legend,
h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>With fieldset</legend>
  <div>No collapse</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <div>No collapse</div>
</fieldset>

<div class="fieldset">
  <h1>Without fieldset</h1>
  <div>Collapse</div>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
  <div>Collapse</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `FIELSET` typo `FIELDSET`! [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvgWKN)

Comment: Yes thanks but it's worst :)

Comment: I usually give 2nd child a negative `top-margin`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `reset.css` file:

```
legend + * {
  -webkit-margin-top-collapse: discard;
}
```

Check out this [updated version of the Codepen example](https://codepen.io/beau/pen/aPxQav) from the question above.

Also demo here…

## Working Demo

```css
legend,
p {
  margin: 20px
}

legend + * {
  /* comment out this line below and click Run to see the difference */
  -webkit-margin-top-collapse: discard;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend <strong>with</strong> collapsing margin below</legend>
  <p>☝ margins collapsed </p>
</fieldset>
```

## Non-Working Demo (for comparison)

```css
legend,
p {
  margin: 20px
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend <strong>without</strong> collapsing margin below</legend>
  <p>☝ margins not collapsed </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>With fieldset</legend>
  <div>No collapse</div>  
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <div>No collapse</div>  
</fieldset>

<div class="fieldset">
  <h1>Without fieldset</h1>
  <div>Collapse</div>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
  <div>Collapse</div>
</div>
```

And here is the updated CSS:

```
.fieldset, fieldset, legend, div, h1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Added float and width :)